# Wordpress, redirect to home page after showing a page

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site, I want to change to something like this.

1. When the user types the home page, show them a page where they type their username and mobile number
2. When Clicking the submit button, I need to redirect them to the home page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could just link tthe button to the wanted page.
Example:
submit
Hope this helps.

Comment: I created two files index.php and indexhome.php, when I tried to redirect as <?php wp_redirect( 'http://www.xxx.co.in/indexhome.php', 301 ); exit; ?>, it says pagenotfound. Any idea

Comment: Why dont u simply link it using html..maybe m getting ur question wrong.